# fastlane package questions:Couldn't find app 'com.xxx.xx' on the account of 'xxx@com.cn' on iTunes Connect

Tags: testflight, fastlane, fastlane-pilot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lleM.png)
this is my first time to use fastlane, i want to upload ipa file to testflight, in the Fastfile, i write this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKOiJ.png)

but when i excuted 'fastlane beta' in command line, it appeared error "Couldn't find app 'com.xxx.RFTestDemo' on the account of 'aaa@xx.com.cn' on iTunes Connect", i don't know what's wrong, hope someone to help me, thanks very much.

Comment: Does the email you are using in for `pilot` have the correct set of permissions on iTunesConnect? Asked in another way, if you log into itunesconnect.apple.com with that same email/password you are using, are you able to see that app and do developer things?

Comment: i haven't create a that app  on ITC yet with that email/pwd,  wether the pilot action don‘t create a new app？

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT 2022: This issue popped back up as I was attempting upload to Testflight**

**FURTHER EDIT: Fastlane 2.204.2 is the official fix - bump to that one or remove the explicit version dependency for 2.204.1 to resolve**

I started seeing the same issue this week after not touching the files for quite some time (we use Deliver and Pilotfiles for upload/submissions).  From Fastlanes release pages: "There is an issue with how App Store Connect API is handling /v1/apps?filter[bundleId]= where the bundle identifier is greater than 25 characters."

As an interim solution please update fastlane versions to point to **2.204.1** (had to manually specify the version in our Gemfile) this is going to be a temp fix though, so watch for upcoming releases and flip back accordingly

Reference https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases

Comment: Thanks, this fixed for me. I faced the same issue, a long time not changing any file, and then suddenly this error. I bumped yesterday Fastlane but it didn't work, but it bumped just up to 2.204.0. I checked here and my bundle has 26 chars. 2.204.1 made Pilot work again.

Comment: Is there a way in App Center to update FastLane

Comment: @VenkataKrishna I don't know of one, but this is typically managed in your local Gemfile if you're leveraging fastlane.  Removing a given version (if hardcoded - as was case for original solution) should do the trick to pull latest available

Comment: I've the latest Fastlane version  2.211.0 and facing the issue

Answer (score 3):

I faced this same issue when running `fastlane ios beta` despite having the app correctly set up on my account, and found the cause to be the app identifier in my project's fastlane configuration was mis-spelt using the wrong case (eg 'com.Pxxx' instead of 'com.pxxx').

Correcting this in the first line of `ios/fastlane/Appfile` fixed the issue for me.

```
app_identifier("com.xxx")
```

Comment: I have had Appfiles setup for years and never changed them and they all give this error now. I've double checked, the identifiers are exact and have not changed. This just randomly started happening the other day.

Comment: Hey I'am having the exact same issue all of a sudden.. could it be the appstore connect API is down? @JeremyF

Comment: Hey @JeremyF and Arnvfx please check my answer and see if that helps you guys out.  Reference: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases